# Problem with Mojo::IOLoop timer before redirect

Tags: perl, mojolicious, morbo

i have a sub in my Mojolicious Controller which is called when a csv file is uploaded through a http post.
After the file is uploaded, a message gets rendered that say "you will be redirected in x seconds".
so i want to implement Mojo::IOLoop::Delay and as callback i use the redirect statement. But i get the following error by Morbo:

```
Mojo::Reactor::EV: Timer failed: Transaction already destroyed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Mojolicious/Plugin/DefaultHelpers.pm line 168.
```

controller code:

```
sub upload {
    my $self = shift;
      # Check file size
      return $self->render(text => 'File is too big.', status => 200)
      if $self->req->is_limit_exceeded;

  # Process uploaded file
  return $self->redirect_to('/') unless my $newCsv = $self->param('fileToUpload');
  my $size = $newCsv->size;
  my $name = $newCsv->filename;
  my $delay = 2;
  $self->render(text => "Thanks for uploading $size byte file $name.<br>
    You will be redirected in $delay seconds");
  Mojo::IOLoop->timer($delay => sub {
    $self->redirect_to('/');
    });
}
```

relevant routes:

```
$r->get('/')->to(controller => 'main', action => 'index');
$r->post('/uploadCsv')->to(controller => 'main', action => 'upload')->name('uploadCsv');
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload` returns after `Mojo::IOLoop->timer` and nothing waits for the timer. You can try using [Mojo::IOLoop->delay](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/IOLoop#delay) and `$delay->wait` instead. But I am not sure how it works. So it might be equivalent to just `sleep`.

Do you really need to redirect from perl code? You can render some js with `setTimeout` for the same effect.

In fact I would recommend moving all text and redirecting to js and render only json with some status information inside `upload`. So you can implement better UI with error handling.

Answer (score 3):

`redirect_to` is effectively a `render` that renders a HTTP 302 response to redirect. You cannot render twice, so even if you keep the transaction around until the `redirect_to` call, it would have already rendered the page. So there are two actual options for what you are trying to do; render a page with javascript that will perform the redirect after a timeout, or render an HTML page with a meta refresh tag which will cause the page to redirect after a delay. This [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#Alternative_way_of_specifying_redirections) discusses both approaches.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have chosen the 3rd solution :) : i implemented a JS-script with a timeout in my .html. do you think this solution is practicable too, or it's not "the best" solution?

Comment: @Chris I think it's fine for what you want to accomplish, the only benefit of the meta-refresh approach is that it doesn't require the user to enable javascript.